# Python: Create a message box with a text entry field using tkinter

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox, messagebox

I know how to make message boxes, and I know how to create textboxes. However, I don't know how to make a message box WITH a textbox in it. I've looked through the tkinter documentation and it seems message boxes are kind of limited.

Is there a way to make a message box that contains a text entry field, or would I have to create a new pop up window from scratch?

Comment: you have to create one from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simpledialog.askstring()` was exactly what I needed.